# How to Add index to a List Column (Azure cosmos ) in Azure Search

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I'm having a complex document in my Cosmos DB like below

```
{
    "id": "e064a694-8e1e-4660-a3ef-6b894e9414f7",
    "Name": "Lidiya Lawrence",
    "languageBatchResult": {
        "id": "Lidiya Lawrence",
        "Languages": [
            {
                "name": "English"
            }
        ]
    },
    "keyPhraseBatchResult": {
        "Keys": [
            "Government of India",
            "Training Co-ordinator",
            "customer support",
            "months"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement Azure Search with this data.

The problem is how should I able to create an index as searchable for the `keyPhraseBatchResult`/`Keys` which is having the list of values?

I already tried to create an index with `keyPhraseBatchResult` in azure search but it's not working. The indexing is working only for `Name` unfortunately

**Update 1**

After adding the `keyphrases` how to map the field now?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To index `/keyPhraseBatchResult/Keys`, you need to first create a [Collection(Edm.String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index#fields-collection-and-field-attributes) [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-create-index-rest-api) field `keyphrases` to store your list.

Then you need to set up your [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb) with a [field mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs#add-field-mappings) from `/keyPhraseBatchResult/Keys` to `keyphrases`.

Comment: pls see my *Update 1* how to field map the `/keyPhraseBatchResult/Keys` to `keyphrases`

Comment: Currently you can't add field mappings in the portal, so you would need to create just the index (in the portal), then create the [datasource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source) and [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer) using REST APIs.

Comment: the data source is already created in portal right, as a first step of creating index? do we need to create again in REST APIs ?

Comment: upvoted, could you please provide me the update for the below? so that I can try that and accept your solution

Comment: Depends on what you've tried already; usually nothing gets created until you configure everything. You can see if a datasource already exists in the `Data sources` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Modeling/Mapping Complex Types in Indexes Feature is [finally implemented by microsoft](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes)

As per that, we have 2 new data types called `Edm.ComplexType` and `Collection(Edm.ComplexType)` with this we can easily map our indexes

[Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types)

**[Note: It is start supported by api-version=2019-05-06]**